# Using Array.map on an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, f#

I have an array of arrays P, which represents a Matrix, as an array of row vectors (that representation is more convenient for my purposes), and I want to extract the column-vector j of that array. My first pass was:

```
let column (M: float[][]) (j: int) =
   Array.map(fun v -> v.[j]) M
```

This fails to compile, telling me that v.[j] is using operator expr.[idx] on an object of indeterminate type. This is puzzling to me, because hovering over v recognizes v as a float[], which I believe is a row vector.

Furthermore, the following code works:

```
let column (M: float[][]) (j: int) =
   Array.map(fun v -> v) M
   |> Array.map (fun v -> v.[j])
```

I fail to understand how the second example is different from the first one. The first map in the second example looks redundant: I am mapping an array to itself, and yet this seems to resolve the type determination problem.

Any help understanding what I am doing wrong or not seeing would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that F# type inference is strictly left to right so that the compiler sees

```
let column (M: float[][]) (j: int) =
   Array.map(fun v -> v.[j])
```

At this point, it knows absolutely nothing about `v` so it throws an error.  This is why the forward pipe operator `|>` is so common - rewriting your code as

```
let column (M: float[][]) (j: int) =
   M |> Array.map(fun v -> v.[j])
```

Is fine.  This is also why your second example works

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Regarding the fact that intellisense properly identifies the type of v, should I infer that it knows more about it than the compiler?

Comment: @Mathias - that would seem to be correct but I don't know how the intellisense works

Answer (score 3):

Since the type checker works from left to right, type of `v` is unspecified although type of `M` is available at some point later. Therefore:

```
let column (M: float[][]) (j: int) =
   M |> Array.map (fun v -> v.[j])
```

or

```
let column M (j: int) =
   Array.map (fun (v: float []) -> v.[j]) M
```

works.

In the second example, `fun v -> v` is ok on any type. So there is no problem with type of array elements. The second part with `|>` works as expected and demonstrates one more point why we should use pipe operators.